# Hide variants that aren't available in Shopify?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, shopify

Right now in default Shopify no matter what you select on style you'll still be able to choose any of those sizes even if it's not available for that style. I followed the instructions here: http://wiki.shopify.com/Linked_Options

It works great except that the second option list has duplicated items in it. Any idea why? here is what I have on my `product-form.liquid`. You can see it in action on my site here: http://gravitypicks.myshopify.com/collections/picks/products/axis

```
{% if product.available %}
  <form action="/cart/add" method="post" class="clearfix product_form shappify_add_to_cart_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-money-format="{{ shop.money_format }}" data-shop-currency="{{ shop.currency }}" id="product-form-{{ product.id }}">

{% if settings.display_inventory_left %}
  <div class="items_left">
    {% if product.variants.first.inventory_management == "shopify" and product.variants.first.inventory_quantity > 0 %}
      <p><em>{{ product.variants.first.inventory_quantity }} {{ settings.inventory_left_text | escape }}</em></p>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
{% endif %}

{% if product.options.size > 1 %}
  <div class="select">
    <select id="product-select-{{ product.id }}" name='id'>
      {% for variant in product.variants %}
        <option {% if variant == product.selected_or_first_available_variant %}selected="selected"{% endif %} value="{{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.title }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
  </div>
{% elsif product.options.size == 1 and (product.variants.size > 1 or product.options[0] != "Title") %}
  <div class="select">
    <label>{{ product.options[0] }}:</label>
    <select id="product-select-{{ product.id }}" name='id'>
      {% for variant in product.variants %}
        <option {% if variant == product.selected_or_first_available_variant %}selected="selected"{% endif %} value="{{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.title }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
  </div>
{% else %}
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ product.variants.first.id }}" />
{% endif %}

  <!-- Bold Apps: Product Options -->
  {% include 'shappify-options' %}
  {% if settings.display_product_quantity %}
  <div class="left">
    <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
    <input type="number" min="1" size="2" class="quantity" name="quantity" id="quantity" value="1" />
  </div>
{% endif %}
<div class="purchase clearfix {% if settings.display_product_quantity %}inline_purchase{% endif %}">
  {% if settings.cart_return == 'back' %}
    <input type="hidden" name="return_to" value="back" />
  {% endif %}
    <input type="submit" name="add" value="{{ settings.add_to_cart_text | escape }}"     class="action_button add_to_cart" />
</div>  
</form>

  {% if product.variants.size > 1 or product.options.size > 1 %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
  // <![CDATA[  
    $(function() {    
      $product = $('#product-' + {{ product.id }});
      new Shopify.OptionSelectors("product-select-{{ product.id }}", { product: {{ product | json }}, onVariantSelected: selectCallback{% if product-form == 'product' %}, enableHistoryState: true{% endif %} }); 
      {% if product.available and product.options.size > 1 %}
        Shopify.linkOptionSelectors({{ product | json }});
      {% endif %}
    });
  // ]]>
    </script>
  {% endif %}
 {% endif %}
```

Here is the JS that is on the page:

```
    <script>
// (c) Copyright 2014 Caroline Schnapp. All Rights Reserved. Contact: mllegeorgesand@gmail.com
// See http://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/advanced-navigation/linked-product-options

var Shopify = Shopify || {};

Shopify.optionsMap = {};

Shopify.updateOptionsInSelector = function(selectorIndex) {
switch (selectorIndex) {
case 0:
var key = 'root';
var selector = jQuery('.single-option-selector:eq(0)');
break;
case 1:
var key = jQuery('.single-option-selector:eq(0)').val();
var selector = jQuery('.single-option-selector:eq(1)');
break;
case 2:
var key = jQuery('.single-option-selector:eq(0)').val();
key += ' / ' + jQuery('.single-option-selector:eq(1)').val();
var selector = jQuery('.single-option-selector:eq(2)');
}
var initialValue = selector.val();
selector.empty();
var availableOptions = Shopify.optionsMap[key];
for (var i=0; i<availableOptions.length; i++) {
var option = availableOptions[i];
var newOption = jQuery('<option></option>').val(option).html(option);
selector.append(newOption);
}
jQuery('.swatch[data-option-index="' + selectorIndex + '"] .swatch-element').each(function() {
if (jQuery.inArray($(this).attr('data-value'), availableOptions) !== -1) {
$(this).removeClass('soldout').show().find(':radio').removeAttr('disabled','disabled').removeAttr('checked');
}
else {
$(this).addClass('soldout').hide().find(':radio').removeAttr('checked').attr('disabled','disabled');
}
});
if (jQuery.inArray(initialValue, availableOptions) !== -1) {
selector.val(initialValue);
}
selector.trigger('change');
};

Shopify.linkOptionSelectors = function(product) {
// Building our mapping object.
for (var i=0; i<product.variants.length; i++) {
var variant = product.variants[i];
if (variant.available) {
// Gathering values for the 1st drop-down.
Shopify.optionsMap['root'] = Shopify.optionsMap['root'] || [];
Shopify.optionsMap['root'].push(variant.option1);
Shopify.optionsMap['root'] = Shopify.uniq(Shopify.optionsMap['root']);
// Gathering values for the 2nd drop-down.
if (product.options.length > 1) {
var key = variant.option1;
Shopify.optionsMap[key] = Shopify.optionsMap[key] || [];
Shopify.optionsMap[key].push(variant.option2);
Shopify.optionsMap[key] = Shopify.uniq(Shopify.optionsMap[key]);
}
// Gathering values for the 3rd drop-down.
if (product.options.length === 3) {
var key = variant.option1 + ' / ' + variant.option2;
Shopify.optionsMap[key] = Shopify.optionsMap[key] || [];
Shopify.optionsMap[key].push(variant.option3);
Shopify.optionsMap[key] = Shopify.uniq(Shopify.optionsMap[key]);
}
}
}
// Update options right away.
Shopify.updateOptionsInSelector(0);
if (product.options.length > 1) Shopify.updateOptionsInSelector(1);
if (product.options.length === 3) Shopify.updateOptionsInSelector(2);
// When there is an update in the first dropdown.
jQuery(".single-option-selector:eq(0)").change(function() {
Shopify.updateOptionsInSelector(1);
if (product.options.length === 3) Shopify.updateOptionsInSelector(2);
return true;
});
// When there is an update in the second dropdown.
jQuery(".single-option-selector:eq(1)").change(function() {
if (product.options.length === 3) Shopify.updateOptionsInSelector(2);
return true;
});
};

</script>
```

Comment: Did you try, inside the variant loop: if variant available, do this?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a liquid newbie... :-/ Where/how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link here helped immensely. I had to do some tweaking to fit my uses but it was 99% there for me.

http://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/advanced-navigation/linked-product-options